# Storing variables in a event-driven message pump?

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I'm trying to setup a basic connection to Azure's ServiceBus and have encountered something wierd in Azures examplecode that have kept me wondering over how variables are stored 'cause I can't get that to work.

An example that works:

```
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>()));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message id: {0}", message.MessageId));
});
```

If I edit this into something like this:

```
string test = string.Empty;
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
    test = String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>());
});
Console.WriteLine("test: "+test); //outputs "test: "
```

It doesn't work anymore. The output will be just "test: ". Shouldn't this work like this or have I missed something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `OnMessage` is asynchronous, `Console.WriteLine` needs to be inside the lambda expression, as `Console.WriteLine` will execute before OnMessage is preempted.

Comment: I see, that explains it. Thank you. But what if one need to to store the data for further use?

Comment: I have edited my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `OnMessage` is an event.
The lambda expression `message => ...` executes when a message arrives.

```
// keep a list if you need one.
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
// the string is allocated immediately.
string test = string.Empty;
// the client will execute the lambda when a message arrives.
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
    // this is executed when a message arrives.
    test = String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>());

    // this will output the message when a message arrives, and 
    // the lambda expression executes.
    Console.WriteLine("test: "+test); //outputs "test: "

    // you could add the message to a list here.
    bag.Add(message.GetBody<string>());
});

// this line of code runs immediately, before the message arrives.
Console.WriteLine("test: "+test); //outputs "test: "
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  If I really needed the last row to contain a message, I could use a sleep?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Streetcred to you my friend. Will use this as solution as fast as I can

Comment: @DaveLar - sleep won't help you, since you don't know when a message will come in. So it may come in time for `test` to have been modified when your last line runs, but it may come in later than that as well. If you want more clarifications, create another question, and don't forget to select an answer if it helped you.